# Understanding the advantages of BF16 vs. FP16 in mixed precision training

Tags: train, numerics

Brain float (BF16) and 16-bit floating point (FP16) both require 2 bytes of memory, but in contrast to FP16, BF16 allows to represent a much larger numerical range than FP16, so under-/overflows won't happen as often. However, this comes at the cost of reduced precision.

In mixed precision training with FP16, the problem of the numerical range is usually tackled with scaling the loss and unscaling it when converting to FP32. The appropriate scaling factor is determined by trial and error, mostly during the first few iterations in training.

So, given that we can solve the problem of the comparatively small numerical range of FP16, what is the benefit of BF16 then?

Comment: First of all, if small values are not crucial, BF16's wider range allows training without scaling at all. Second, while small values "may be crucial or not", under-/over-flow is an absolute killer so it is more critical to protect against. Finally, scaling isn't "free", scaling can still lead to loss of information during scaling and unscaling from FP16 and can potentially affect accuracy.

Comment: @usεr11852 In my experience, the number of iterations with under-/overflows is relatively small, only a few dozens of iterations as compared to 100.000s+ of overall training iterations. So, I think it shouldn't be such a big issue?

Comment: I agree, but we only need once to go from 32768 to -32768 to absolutely bomb our trajectory. (Nice answer below by the way, I have upvoted it - as I have upvoted the question.)

Comment: Thanks. As far as I know, under-/overflows lead to NaNs/infs, which in turn can be detected by the training logic to trigger an adaptation of the loss scaling factor. At least, this is how it's handled in Megatron-LM and DeepSpeed.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research on my own and came up with the following two advantages of BF16 mixed precision training:

- **Less memory**: Even though BF16 and FP16 both require 2 bytes per parameter, the memory requirements of BF16 training are actually lower than in FP16 training. Because of the low precision of BF16, the gradients in BF16 training are directly stored in FP32 and consequently do not require an extra copy [[1]](https://github.com/NVIDIA/Megatron-LM?tab=readme-ov-file#distributed-optimizer).
- **No loss scaling**: As pointed out in the comments above, BF16 requires no loss scaling as opposed to FP16 and may lead to a better accuracy.
- **Faster**: Since BF16 is basically the FP32 number's first 2 bytes, converting between BF16 and FP32 is as easy as discarding the last 2 bytes of the FP32 number and copying the BF16 number into the first 2 bytes of the FP32 number's storage location. Converting between FP16 and FP32 instead requires more logic because of the differently sized mantissa [[2]](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/11/15/bfloat16/).

  Furthermore, in FP16 mixed precision training, gradients are constructed in FP16, then converted to FP32 for the parameter update. This step isn't needed in BF16 training because gradients are directly stored in FP32.

  Lastly, the number of operations per iteration is reduced a bit because gradient/loss scaling isn't needed anymore.
- **Silicon area of FMA units**: [Osorio et al. (2022)](https://doi.org/10.1109/TETC.2022.3187770) mention that the silicon area of fused multiply-add (FMA) units grows quadratically with the mantissa length, so specialized BF16 hardware can achieve a higher throughput than FP32 units with the same chip size.

For now, I leave this question open and hope for a more authoritative answer. Above advantages are based on theoretical analysis and not entirely backed by experimental results. In my experiments, the throughput is consistently higher in BF16 training than FP16 training, but there are a few configurations in a distributed setting where the memory requirements of BF16 exceed those of FP16.

Consequently, I believe the higher speed is the most compelling advantage of BF16, while no loss scaling and less memory requirement are either contributing factors or not generally true.

Comment: Nice answer. Agreed on the speed being probably the biggest selling point.